# What HTTP header code does URL-Rewrite return?

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, iis

If I used the native URL-Rewrite module to rewrite (not redirect) a URL, does it return 302, 301, or 200? Is this method OK to use for a permanent URL rewrite?

Here is sample code for the redirect:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewriter" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="foobar" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/actual/foobar.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the rule is only rewriting the URL, it should return a standard '200' HTTP header code (assuming there are no other errors).  If you had used a redirect action type instead of rewrite, then you would have received a 301 or 302 HTTP response code depending on how the rule was configured.  There are a variety of tools available that you can install on your local client to view the HTTP response codes that are being returned to the browser.  A very popular one is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which provides a lot of monitoring details.  These types of tools can be very useful when debugging rewrite and redirect rules.